# How to create SPD Task to everyone in a group separately?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, groups, tasks

Is it possible to assign a simple SPD To-Do-Item to everyone in a group separately so that individual tasks are given to everyone?

Comment: Are you using SP foundation or Sharepoint server?

Comment: SharePoint Server is being used

Comment: Have you tried using StartApprovalProcess action?

Comment: it has to be a simple to-do task because the workflow isn't working on document level

Comment: You can use StartApprovalProcess  on listitems also

Comment: It is a website workflow and has nothing to do with list items or documents. Sorry for not clarifying that earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using StartApprovalProcess Action, the user can assign a task to one or many persons or to a Sharepoint group for approval process and it will create tasks for each member in the approval list.

1. Open the respective Sharepoint site on SPD2010
2. Click on "Workflows" from the left navigation
3. Select any of the available workflow template ( for example select Reusable Workflow)
4. Give appropriate name and select the content type or choose the default value based on requirement
5. Then select "StartApprovalProcess" from the Ribbon menu
6. Just hover the mouse on the line which is "Start Appr........"
7. You can find the context menu dropdown at the right corner of the selected line
8. Select that context menu and click on Properties
9. Then one popup will open with all the properties for this Action
10. You can find one of the properties named as "ExpandGroups" and it's default value is "No"
11. Change the value from "No" to "Yes" and then click on OK

http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/Assigning-tasks-to-each-member-using-SPD2010-Workflow-1140.php

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I have to use a simple To-Do task, because the workflow isn't working on document level (website workflow). I looked into the properties of the task to see if there's also an "ExpandGroups" property (because that's exactly what i need) but simple To-Do Tasks do not seem to have it

Comment: Is this site workflow?

Comment: Yes, site workflow which has to create to-do tasks for everyone in group (not for the group itself)

Comment: I don't think you can assign simple to do task to each user individually.